# Body parser deprecated undefined extended: provide extended option

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I am getting this error when trying to run my code and don't really know how to solve it. I don't really know the codebase because I'm new to it, so I'm completely lost and have no idea what to do.

```
body-parser deprecated undefined extended: provide extended option index.js:20:20
COMMON_CONFIG.mode === "development" false
Listening on port undefined
```

edit: 
package.json:

```
**{
  "name": "audio-guide-backend",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "repository": "https://gitlab.com/islandica/audio-guide-backend.git",
  "license": "MIT",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "dev": "nodemon index.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "crypto-random-string": "^3.0.1",
    "dotenv": "^8.0.0",
    "ejs": "^2.6.2",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-session": "^1.16.2",
    "pg": "^7.11.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^1.19.1"
  }
}
**
```

Edit 2: This is how my index.js looks like:

```
require("dotenv").config();
const express = require("express");
const http = require("http");
const session = require("express-session");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const { SERVER_CONFIG } = require("./config");

const app = express();

const server = http.createServer(app);

app.set("view engine", "ejs");

app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  // if (req.url === "/api/login") console.log(req);
  next();
});
app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
app.use(
  session({
    secret: "keyboard cat",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true
  })
);

// ROUTES
require("./routes")(app);

// NOT FOUND
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.status(404);

  res.format({
    html: function() {
      res.render("404");
      // res.render("404", { url: req.url });
    },
    json: function() {
      res.json({ message: "Not found" });
    },
    default: function() {
      res.type("txt").send("Not found");
    }
  });
});

// INTERNAL ERROR
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.format({
    html: function() {
      res.render("500");
    },
    json: function() {
      res.json({ message: "server error: " + err.message });
    },
    default: function() {
      res.type("txt").send("server error: " + err.message);
    }
  });
  res.send("server error: " + err.message);
  /*res.render("500", {
    message:
      COMMON_CONFIG.mode === "development"
        ? err.message
        : "Internal server error"
  });*/
});

server.listen(SERVER_CONFIG.port, err => {
  if (err) {
    console.log("Error occured");
  } else {
    console.log(`Listening on port ${SERVER_CONFIG.port}`);
  }
});
```

It looks like my post is mostly code, so I'm adding more details.

Comment: Please update the question and post your code for us to review. Are you using express?

Comment: Could you also share your package.json or at least the dependencies. Specifically the version of express (or whatever framework is using body-parser) and the version of body-parser?

Comment: edited @DavidKamer. Yes I'm using express, however I don't have any experience in express. I've been assigned this project just now, so I don't know anything.

Comment: Okay, can you share your index.js? Specifically anywhere you have `process.env` and `express.json()`. If you see one of express' functions being called elsewhere, that too. That's body-parser in version 4.16+ of express.

Comment: @Tauronek you might use the JavaScript chat room here on SO if you keep running into problems. Always search for an answer first though. If you're new to it, then the chat might be a better place to learn.

Comment: I shared my index.js and installed body-parser.

Answer (score 2):

`Listening on port undefined`

This means that you don't have the port set. I see you're using `dotenv`, so the first place to check is your `.env` file in the root directory. If one wasn't created, make it and add whatever the name is for the environmental variable referenced in index.js. It's likely `PORT`.

Next you'll want to review the options you're passing into `express.json()` or whatever `body-parser` function you're calling. It's passing an `undefined` into that also.

Check your .env file or your system environmental variables and add the ones needed.

EDIT:

Check `SERVER_CONFIG` in the `config` file. That's where you should have you environmental variables that would usually be in .env. It's possible and likely that `SERVER_CONFIG` just consumes the dotenv package.

Also, you do not need `const server = http.createServer(app);` Just replace the call to `server.listen(...)` with `app.listen(...)`

Remove bodyParser, and use `express.urlencoded({extended: true})`

Comment: @Tauronek check my revisions too. Basically it looks like an older project didn't get finished being updated. You don't need body-parser. Express has it built in now. You just need to define a port number in your config, and you need to add `{extended: true}` (or false) into the `urlencoded` call

Answer (score 0):

Since the bodyParser is deprecated, I had resolved this issue by setting the extended:true option on the app.

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));
```

instead of

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
```